# How to give direct login link in Mail in c# application

Tags: c#

I have an application where whenever an upload is made a mail will be sent to  the admin.From the mail admin needs to login directly to the application by clicking a link and he should approve or reject the uploaded file.Mine is a c# web application.Can anyone help me out in doing this securely...

Answer (score 0):

Idealy if you don't want the admin to have to login with a username and password and other authentication like certificate and kerberos are not an option then you should not have the link do anything more then take the admin to the page so they can approve or reject the upload.

Other points are:

1. Use a one time password (OTP) / random string to associate the item that need to be approved/reject with a specific admin. If more then one admin then the OTP will be unique for each.
2. Limit the time of the OTP's validity.
3. Log it.
4. Require full authentication if anything more then approving or rejecting that upload is required.

Comment: Thanku for your suggestion,i wil try and let u know

Comment: @3prema4: if you like the suggestions and think they worth trying out, please upvote the answer.